# Those who / Anyone who / Whoever

Tags: american-english

Since in English it is not possible to start sentences similar to this with a ***Who***, I would like to know if ***Those who***, ***Anyone who*** and ***Whoever*** are interchangeable. Also, which one is the best one in a formal text (that is not gender neutral).

> ***Those who*** say that don't know what they are talking about.
>
> ***Anyone who*** says that doesn't know what he is talking about.
>
> ***Whoever*** says that doesn't know what he is talking about.

Comment: Anyone who dares wins?

Comment: It used to be possible; Hamlet says _Who steals my purse steals trash_. But that's no help. All of the constructions listed are grammatical and common, and pretty much interchangeable, subject to individual tastes or habits. There are more; _someone who, people who, a person who, ..._

Comment: The most formal structure still in use, but which is not gender neutral is: "He who says that doesn't now what he is talking about."  This is like the well known phrase: "He who hesitates is lost."

Comment: @JohnLawler I think that similar constructions are still possible. For example: "Who painted that portrait is an issue that does not concern art historians." (The meaning is a bit different from that of your Hamlet example, though.)

Comment: Yes, that's an embedded question, not a headless relative.